Настройка DNS для IIS
Не понимаю, почему не отображается сайт на IIS при переходе по ссылке mylocalsite.local. Тестирую пока на виртуалке.
Настройки следующие:
IIS:

DNS:


IP:


Наверняка потому что у неведомой "виртуалки" другая "внешняя" сеть.
